# Baseboard heating - some zones stopped heating

Tags: baseboard, zoned-heating

Yesterday afternoon between 3 and 6pm, two zones of our baseboard heating system stopped working.  There are 4 zones: main floor, 2 basement zones, and 1 zone for the upstairs bedrooms (split level home).  We have tried a few different fixes - bleeding for air, increasing boiler pressure, manually running the upstairs zone constantly.  Nothing has worked.  Any suggestions/help would be much appreciated.  [Here is a google doc](https://docs.google.com/document/d/14Ck9y8R4Ts_rR7tpwpHjFCgyl42keUyuyVIxHpM2kJ8/edit?usp=sharing) with pics (couldn't compress them for this posting).

Comment: 2 zones stopped working?  those looks like honey well zc, are they?  when you say manually running, are you manually locking open the zc?

Comment: Are you getting water flow but the water's not hot, or are you not getting water flow at all?

Comment: We are getting constant water flow at the baseboard, but it’s cold.  

They are Honeywell ZCs.  We manually put the ZC in the “open/on” position, but that didn’t help.